# HorizontalPager content pages with different height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Inside a scrollable column I have a horizontal pager with two pages on it. One of them contains a very long list of content, while the other one is much shorter. On the smaller one I have a huge area at the bottom that I can scroll down on with no content, I suspect because of the height of the long list. Also, if I scrolled to the bottom on the longer page, and then swipe to the other page, then I just get a blank screen, and have to scroll far up to the actual content.

How can I limit the user from scrolling down below the actual content on the shorter page?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.TopStart)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {

    someOtherContent() // for example around 400.dp height
    
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ) { i ->
        when (i) {
            0 -> {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(450.dp)
                ) {
                    ... not too much content
                }
            }
            1 -> {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(2000.dp)
                ) {
                    ... many rows of content
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a Column as shown in your code, use a LazyColumn and DON'T set the height. LazyColumn automatically resizes the height based on the content. I use this in my HorizontalPager and have small and large lists without the issue you have.

Comment: Do you have a verticalScroll modifier on either the pager or your column?

Comment: @ScottCooper yes, my mistake. I've updated my question to include the parent of the pager.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the issue but I'm not really sure what you can do about it. The root column's scroll height is as tall as the pager, which in turn is as tall as its tallest child. You may need to remove the scroll modifier from the parent column and implement some kind of nested scrolling